# Why is my IF statement not working to define membership level?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I am very new to PHP and trying to get an IF statement to work to change the membership level based on the possibility of multiple answers provided in the registration form. However, it's not working. If anyone can help me understand what I am doing wrong/missing that would be a great help. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
function my_pmpro_checkout_level($level)
{

if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['registrationlevel']) && $level->id == '1' ) {
if (( $_REQUEST['registrationlevel'] == 'eligibleforlimited' && $_REQUEST['experience'] != 'morethansixyears') || ($_REQUEST['registrationlevel'] == 'eligibleforlimited' && $_REQUEST['timeassesment'] == 'no')) {
    $level->id = '3';
  } elseif ( $_REQUEST['registrationlevel'] == 'eligibleforprovisional' && $_REQUEST['experience'] != 'noexperience') {
    $level->id = '3'}
}

return $level;
}
add_filter("pmpro_checkout_level", "my_pmpro_checkout_level");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What is happening compared to what you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear. The code basically only works for the first IF, the level does not change from Level 1 to Level 3 for the rest. For example: if in the registration form 'eligibleforlimited' is selected and any of the options not equal to 'morethansixyears' is selected it works great and changes from Level 1 to Level 3, but if 'eligbleforlimited' and 'morethansixyears' is selected and 'timeassesment' is equal to 'no' the Level stays at Level 1 and does not change to Level 3.

Comment: The IF statement behavior you've described looks like it should work with what you've posted, but are you sure you have tested the code you pasted here? It currently has a syntax error (missing semicolon) that would cause a fatal error on the page and none of the code to run.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Sorry I have the semicolon instead of the curly bracket in my code on the site so no fatal error. Just not working properly as per my set conditions.

Comment: Try echoing out both the $_REQUEST variables in question and the level->id property in your code, then test the submission. Are the correct properties coming through to trigger that IF statement?